# How can I run Q# program in Azure Quantum

Tags: quantum-algorithms, q#

I have already made a small Q# program and ran it using Python on VSCode, my question is **how can I run it on Azure Quantum** to make it run faster?

- Q# program :

  ```
  namespace QubitTest {
  open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
  open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
  open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;
  open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
  open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

  operation QChange() : Int {
  // on retourne un qubit   
   using ( q = Qubit()) {
   for (i in 1..500000){
       H(q);
       Message($" Qubit {i} : {q}");
   }
   return 0;
   }
  }

  }
  ```
- Python Simulation :

  ```
   import qsharp

   from QubitTest import QChange 

   QChange.simulate()
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Quantum is in private preview right now. You can sign up to request early access [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/quantum/#contact).